# What is Attribute in C#

Tags: c#, attributes

Sometimes I see them with methods, classes etc. 
What does it do? 
When should i use them?
Example:

```
[Obsolete]
public static void MyMethod()
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: [Attribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx)  use them when you need the functionality they provide

Comment: You might want to take a minute to read [Ask] and take the [Tour].  A very great many basic questions already have answers here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attribute is a declarative tag that is used to convey information to runtime about the behaviors of various elements like classes, methods, structures, enumerators, assemblies etc. in your program. You can add declarative information to a program by using an attribute
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx